# Fixing Whirlpool Oven Fans and Doors

Tags: repair, oven

I have an older Whirlpool oven that has recently started to make noise when I turn it on. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the oven fan. In addition, the door does not seal too well so if I can fix that at the same time I'd be really happy. Is this the sort of thing that can be fixed by myself or a repair person, or am I looking at a new oven? I'd like to think that most ovens are very serviceable, but I am not sure where to start figuring it out.

Comment: What makes you think it is a fan?  Is it a convection oven?  What is the model number?

Comment: I'm not sure if its a convection oven. It is electric. The model number is RBS245PD86. I believe its the fan because the noise and vibration that is happening seems to be coming from something spinning pretty fast. I wouldn't know what else would be in an oven that might do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your reasoning is good - it's pretty easy to pick out a the sound of a fan hitting against something. I recommend RepairClinic.com. They have a great site for appliance parts, and lots of info and schematics for what parts are available and how to replace them. You already have the manufacturer and model number, so you are ready to go.
Hope this helps.